# Conditional Discrete Distributions Problem with Fruit Flies

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Here I have a problem related to conditional distributions; I feel like the $RW$ and $WR$ combinations are preventing me from understanding further.

The alleles of eye color in a male fruit fly are (R,W). The alleles for the mating female are $(R,W)$. Their offspring receive one allele for eye color from each parent. If an offspring ends up with $(W,W), (R,W)$, or $(W,R)$ its eyes look white. Let $X$ equal the number of offspring with white eyes. Let $Y$ equal the number of white eyed offspring having $(R,W)$ or $(W,R)$ alleles.

A) If the number of offspring is $n=400$ how is $X$ distributed? If $X=300$ how is $Y$ distributed?

B) What's $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$?

C) What's $E(Y|X=300)$ and $Var(Y|X=300)$?

I would really appreciate help especially in part A, where I just am not sure how to get started.

Answer (score 2):

An individual offspring of a male RW and a female RW will have white eyes if it is
WW, RW, WR (but not RR). Because WW, RW, WR and RR are equally likely, it will have white eyes with probability $3/4.$ The $n = 400$ offspring have independent genotypes.

Thus, the random variable 
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 400, p = 3/4))$ and $E(X) = np = 300,\,
V(X) = np(1-p) = ??$

Of the approximately 300 white-eyed offspring, $2/3$ will be of type RW or WR.

*Note:* As a warning about the use of this notation, it is not possible to
distinguish between RW and WR, so offspring with mixed alleles are
sometimes written just as RW. In that case RW has probability $1/2$ and
WW has probability $1/4.$ This problem follows a 'simplified' notation
to avoid dealing with unequal probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

If $X\sim \text{Bin}(400,p)$ and $Y|X \sim \text{Bin}(300,q)$$

$p = \frac{3}{4},q = \frac{2}{3}$

I interpret this the following way. The probability mass function for $X$ is:
$$P(X=x) = \binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$$
The conditional mass function for $Y$ given $X=x$ is:
$$P(Y=y|X=x) = \binom{x}{y}q^{y} (1-q)^{x-y}$$

$E(X) = np, Var(X) = np(1-p)$

$E(Y/X=300) = 300q, Var(Y/X=300) = 300q(1-q)$

Comment: Why is q 2/3 and not 1/4?

Comment: Of the X which are three combinations (WW),(RW),(WR), Y is only (RW) and (WR).  Hence $q = \frac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

We need to make some assumption to answer this question.

A possible assumption is that it is equally likely to obtain $R$ or $W$ from a parent. Also, we might want to assume for each offspring, the outcome is independnet, that is i.i.d assumption.

With those assumptions, we can conclude that the probability to get white eyes would be $\frac34$. There are $400$ offsprings. Can you state the distribution of $X$ now?

Comment: Your answer (+1) appeared while I was typing mine (with interruptions).